# Lightbox / image slider module tutorial

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1

I have made a lightbox in jQuery, and I want to convert it to a module in Magento. With this module, I want a dropdown option under CMS, and be able to add galleries.

Then, I want to create a shortcode, to call these galleries inside a cms page or static block.

But I can't find any tutorial that can help me with that. I know the base of making a module, but now I want to upload images, make them into a gallery and display them on a CMS page.

If someone knows a good tutorial, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to create **2 Admin grid**.

1. To add Galleries
2. To add Images in that Galleries

From R&D i got one [Extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-gallery-with-categories.html) related to above idea. (Not tested)

Then you can add custom `select field` in  "Page Information" tab -> cms -> pages.

You can refer this [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19856/45103) for that.

Edit in that answer : Instead of text we want select field. So in `\local\ Sandipvaghasiya\CMS\Model\Observer.php` use select field (Refer below)

```
$fieldset->addField('gallery', 'select', array(
          'label'     => 'gallery',
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'values'    => //array of galleries name,
          'name'      => 'gallery',
      ));
```

To get galleries name array, create function in existing model of above Image Gallery extension

```
Mage::getModel('[module]/[model file name]')->getNameArray()
```

create function getNameArray in that model file and return all gallery name array.

**Note :** Its a rough idea to start.